# Modify headers of proxied request

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, express, http-proxy

I'm IP restricting a pure client-side CORs demo application which interacts with an authenticated third-party API. I've got a "middleware" server running which I use to proxy requests from the CORs app to the third-party API, but I am **having trouble injecting Basic Authentication credentials into those proxied requests.**

```
isAllowed = (req, res, next) -> # Do IP check here.

base64Encode = (unencoded) -> new Buffer(unencoded or '').toString 'base64'

app.all "/demoproxy/*", isAllowed, (req, res) ->

  req.url = "/" + req.url.split("/").slice(2).join("/")

  userPass = base64Encode "#{process.env.DEMO_USERNAME}:#{process.env.DEMO_PASSWORD}"

   # This doesn't work.
   # res.setHeader 'Authorization',  "Basic #{userPass}"

   # This doesn't work either.
   ###res.oldWriteHead = res.writeHead

   res.writeHead = (statusCode, headers) ->

     headers = { }
     headers['Authorization'] = "Basic #{userPass}"
     res.oldWriteHead statusCode, headers###

    proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy
      target:
        host: 'remote-api.com'
        port: 80

    proxy.proxyRequest req, res
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you want to set the authorization header on the request (req) object in this case, not the response (res). If remote-api.com is what needs to be authenticated against then it needs to know that with the request you send to it. Maybe try the following before making the `proxy.proxyRequest` request

```
req.headers["authorization"] = "Basic #{userPass}"
```

With the `req` object there isn't a setHeader function, the headers property is just a javascript object/map. Hope that helps out...

Comment: So, I tried that. But it doesn't come through the same as other Basic Auth? Updated question.

Comment: Have you tried setting req.headers['authorization'] as well? According to the node HTTP docs (http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers), the headers object has all lower-cased, so if it's not working when setting the upper-cased header, perhaps the proxy is only looking at the lower-cased version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works for me, as an example:

```
# Demo server requiring basic authentication
servAuth = require("http").createServer (req, res) ->
  if auth = req.headers?.authorization
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.end "Good job, you sent '#{auth}'"
  else
    res.statusCode = 401
    res.end "How about you authenticate first?"
servAuth.listen(8090)

# Proxy server which checks the IP address and then proxies the request
servProxy = require("http-proxy").createServer (req, res, proxy) ->
  checkIP req, (err, isOK) ->
    # something wrong happened even with the IP address checking
    if err
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end "Sorry, everything got fargled", "ascii"
    # IP address not allowed
    else if not isOK
      res.statusCode = 403
      res.end "You ain't from around here, are you?", "ascii"
    # all good, proxy the request with basic auth added
    else
      userPass = new Buffer("#{process.env.USERNAME}:#{process.env.PASSWORD}", "ascii")
      userPass = userPass.toString("base64")
      req.headers.authorization = "Basic #{userPass}"
      proxy.proxyRequest req, res, {
        host: "localhost"
        port: 8090
      }
servProxy.listen(8080)

# asynchronous IP address checking
checkIP = (req, done) ->
  # TODO: implement whatever custom IP checking
  # this example just says everything is OK
  done( null, true )
```